# ¿Como deshabilitar un item de un Kendo ToolBar en tiempo de ejecucion KendoUI?

Tags: jquery, kendoui

Como puedo colocar enable (TRUE O FALSE) un item del KendoToolBar he tratado de hacer esto, pero no funciona

```
var toolBar = $("#toolbar_1592").data("kendoToolBar");
toolBar.options.items[0].enable =false;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logre solucionarlo (agregando esto al dataSource del toolbat):

```
change: function (e) {
    var totalElementos = dsDocumentos.total();
    var toolBar = $("#toolbar_1592").data("kendoToolBar");
   toolBar.enable("#btnNew", true); //disables the initially disabled command
},
```